# Custom validation in the clean method triggers before checking the fields exist or not in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have the following code in my models file in Django:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    foo = models.IntegerField()
    bar = models.IntegerField()

    def validate_foo_bar(self):
        self._validation_errors = {}
        if self.foo > self.bar:
            self._validation_errors['foo'] = ['Must be greater than bar.']
            self._validation_errors['bar'] = ['Must be less than foo.']

    def clean(self):
        self.validate_foo_bar()
        if bool(self._validation_errors):
            raise ValidationError(self._validation_errors)
        super(MyModel, self).clean()
```

Hopefully the idea is clear. I check for errors in the clean method and raise them if they occur. When I use an admin form to create an object, if I leave the `foo` and `bar` fields empty, I get the following error:

```
if self.foo > self.bar:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

Why is this happening? Shouldn't the requirement check trigger before the method I wrote? Thanks for any help.

**EDIT**

Due to the nature of the answers and comments, I feel compelled to add this. I know the problem can be solved simply by doing the following:

```
def validate_foo_bar(self):
    self._validation_errors = {}
    if self.foo and self.bar:
        if self.foo > self.bar:
            self._validation_errors['foo'] = ['Must be greater than bar.']
            self._validation_errors['bar'] = ['Must be less than foo.']
```

However, that is missing the point because shouldn't this check be done by the built-in form methods themselves **before** the `validate_foo_bar()` method is triggered?

Comment: that's the error. We can not compare None (empty) with None. if you are using this function, you should make sure both fields get value.

Comment: try to check if self.foo and self.bar have values before comparison.

Comment: try "if self.bar and self.foo:" before comparing them.

Comment: @sandeep If I understand correctly, the OP is asking as to why the validation does not pick up the `NoneType` before the `clean` method is called.

Comment: @sandeep Daniel is exactly right.

Comment: @DanielHolmes, I just checked..it's not calling validate_foo_bar(), it's calling clean(). put "raise ValidationError(self._validation_errors)" in validate method and comment clean(), it will not show the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects), the `clean_fields` method is called before the `clean` method. The `clean_fields` method in fact skips validation for fields with a `None` type:

```
def clean_fields(self, exclude=None):
        """
        Clean all fields and raise a ValidationError containing a dict
        of all validation errors if any occur.
        """
        if exclude is None:
            exclude = []

        errors = {}
        for f in self._meta.fields:
            if f.name in exclude:
                continue
            # Skip validation for empty fields with blank=True. The developer
            # is responsible for making sure they have a valid value.
            raw_value = getattr(self, f.attname)
            if f.blank and raw_value in f.empty_values:
                continue
            try:
                setattr(self, f.attname, f.clean(raw_value, self))
            except ValidationError as e:
                errors[f.name] = e.error_list

        if errors:
            raise ValidationError(errors)
```

You can read up more about the reasons *why* [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22921), where it says:

> It is valid based on blank=True though. A use case for blank=True, null=False would be a field that gets populated in save(), for example. If we changed the behavior, it would be backwards incompatible and wouldn't allow this use case anymore. If you want the field required for model validation but not for form validation, then you should drop blank=True on the model and customize the form.

Comment: This is interesting, but my fields do not have `blank=True`. They are all required.